# jQuery keypress event problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-3

I have a function (filterLeads) that I wish to call both when a form field is moved away from (blur) and when the enter key is pressed within a form field.

```
$('#filter input, #filter select').blur(filterLeads);
$('#filter input, #filter select').keypress(function(e){if(e.which == 13) {filterLeads();}});
```

The blur works correctly but I am having a problem with the keypress event. The event does not appear to be fired unless something comes before the call to filterLeads(); for example:

```
$('#filter input, #filter select').keypress(function(e){if(e.which == 13) {alert(e.which);filterLeads();}});
```

This correctly calls filterLeads() after acknowledging the alert (which shows the correct key code).

Any ideas?
(Browser FF 3.0)

Comment: The `alert` window popping up causes `blur` to fire, which might explain why that makes that work.

Comment: Does filterLeads expect the event as parameter?

Comment: Please show us the `filterLeads()` function.

Comment: I have worked out that it is because filterLeads() is using the 'this' object which is set to window object when called by the keypress event rather than the form element object as it is when called by the blur event.

Comment: pass in the event object to filterLeads, problem solved :)

Comment: I have replaced my usage of 'this' in filterLeads with e.target and all is working as it should. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are only targeting FF... but you should also include [all non-FF browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) by using `e.keyCode`. Also `keypress` may not be best event to use according to [this information](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html).

Try something like this:

```
$("#filter input, #filter select").keyup(function(e){
 var key = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
 if( key == 13 ){ filterLeads(e) }
});
```

Comment: The code is actually being used in an internal web app for the company that I work for and we can guarantee that Firefox will be used to access it. Having said that I am very keen to write cross browser code and that information is very useful - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a try: You should `return false;` from within the anonymous function, because else the form (if there is one) containing the fields gets submitted and the page is reloaded.

If filterLeads expects the event as parameter, don't forget to write: `filterLeads(e)`.

And if nothing else helps: Fire `blur()`:

```
$('#filter input, #filter select').keypress(function(e){$(e.target).blur();});
```

(jQuery-fied, because there could be custom jQuery events attached).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The page isn't being reloaded when the enter is pressed so I don't think the form action is being triggered (there is no submit button).

Comment: Try to put your action on the keyup event. Any changes?

Answer (score 0):

just add `e.preventDefault();` inside your event handler, like this:

```
  $('#filter input, #filter select').keypress(function(e){if(e.which == 13) {filterLeads(); e.preventDefault(); }});
```

Comment: This is basically the same as returning false, if there are no other event handlers registered.